# Record the output of a .cgi stream in Java

Tags: java, stream, video-streaming, cgi, video-capture

I have a URL of an IP Camera (like this: http://abc.blabla.hello.net/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=1234 ).
This camera is recording 24/7 and I would like to create a video file of the recordings from the last 24h every 24h.

How can I achieve this? I tried the search a lot but could not find anything.
There has to be a way to do this.

Comment: 24 hrs is a long time to keep an http connection open. Is there a documented API for the camera? Have you tried using curl to make sure that the URL you supplied streams video?

Comment: What's your OS? Have you considered using `curl` instead of Java? `curl <URL> -o - >> "someFile.video"`

Comment: I can also have 24 1h-videos. The model of the camera is "Foscam 18918" and [here](http://www.themadhermit.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/FI8918W-CGI-Commands.pdf) are the CGI-Commands if you need them.
I user Windows 10 (but I can run ubuntu on a VM) so I did not use curl. But when I type the URL into a web browser, I can see the stream.
I will try curl and report back.

Comment: Ok when I try curl <URL> I get this response:
`$ <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>401 Unauthorized</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#cc9999"><H4>401 Unauthorized</H4>
Authorization required.
</BODY></HTML>`

But when I paste the same url into my web browser it works. username and password are in the url. 
Strange

Comment: ok I am 1 step further. I tried `wget -o myvideo.video --user=admin --password=1234 http://abc.blabla.hello.net/videostream.cgi` and it worked.
But I could not open it with any video player I know.

So I opened it up with notepad and the structure is like this:
--ipcamera
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 41126

many lines with symbols like kBI’¤Fy­"C-Ä

and then again
--ipcamera
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 41170

How can I open it?